# Equivalent to Cryptography library

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I have a question regarding `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography` in Microsoft Patters and Practices => Enterprise Library 4.1 Oktober 2008?

Basically in my SharePoint 2007 applicatin i was using this reference `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Security.Cryptography`, but now when I've imported this solution to sharepoint 2010, and visual studio 2010 i cannot find this dll anymore ...

I found on msdn that it is not used anymore ..., so my question is:
- can i get this from previous version and use in 2010
- is there a recent equivalent for this?

I'm using this only like this once: `Cryptographer.EncryptSymmetric(string, string)`

Any adivse?

Comment: Why cant you use a newer api that comes with .net 4.0. Otherwise you will have to download the older library and install it everywhere.

Comment: but what is the newer version?

Comment: Not knowing the exact use of this library in your code. I cannot really suggest anything with confidence but System.Security.Cryptography is your easiest fix that comes with .Net

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to refactor code for the new libraries your best bet is to include that dll and all dependent dlls as part of your solution package and deploy them in the GAC.

To find dependent dlls you can either use reflector and check the references, or use trial and error.

To include a dll as part of your solution use the procedure described here:

[Include 3rd party dll in the Sharepoint project while packaging the wsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521697/include-3rd-party-dll-in-the-sharepoint-project-while-packaging-the-wsp)